# how to create on click event after drilldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, highcharts

I have following drilldown with highcharts.

Where I need to put on click event if I would need to forward to url after drilldown?

http://jsfiddle.net/w6kmxnrc/

```
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Computer',
            id: 'blend.exe',

            data: [
                ['daa', 1] ]
        },

        {
            name: 'Computer',
            id: 'chrome.exe',
            data: [
                ['duu', 1] ]
        }

        ]
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, add an `events` object in your `drilldown.series` objects.

example:

```
events: {
    click: function (event) {
        console.log('blend drilldown clicked');
    }
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6kmxnrc/1/

Check the console when you click on them.

Read more [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events)

Comment: Thanks. Some how it will not show me drilldown after adding url? http://jsfiddle.net/w6kmxnrc/6/

Comment: @user3707994 there is a problem with the format of your data object, if I'm not mistaken. Fixed it for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/w6kmxnrc/7/